# Simple typewriter program error

Tags: java

So I am getting an error that doesn't seem to make any sense, and the solution is most likely staring at me in the face. I do understand the "String index out of range: XX", but it seems to change that value even if I input the same string multiple times. It says (unknown source) which I presume is the phrase variable? And I do see that the error is occurring at line 85, which prints the phrase. However, everything looks fine and dandy to my slightly-novice eye. Any wisdom to shed?

Source:

[image: Code]

[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBfnW.jpg).

Comment: It would help if you posted the relevant source code.

Comment: I posted a picture link. Does that help?

Comment: Post the actual code here, not a screenshot.

Comment: @user2188341 It is not as useful as actual text, because then we cannot easily copy-paste the code somewhere for testing, and the text might not be as easily viewable (such as with your photo, the text is quite small).

Comment: To answer the question itself, use `i < phrase.length()` and `String.charAt()` instead of `String.substring()`

Comment: @NullUserException Don't forget removing the `;` right after the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is

```
for (i = 0; i <= phrase.length(); i++); {
```

should be

```
for (i = 0; i <= phrase.length(); i++) {
```

(removed semi-colon at the end)

**Explanation:**

Your code reformatted:

```
for (i = 0; i <= phrase.length(); i++)
  ;

{
  pause();
  System.out.print(...)
}
```

Only the `;` is in the for-loop. The `{ ... }` is a separate statement (i.e. not part of the for-loop).

Putting the variable declaration inside the loop will generally prevent this from happening in future: (because the `i` reference outside the loop will generate an error)

```
for (int i = 0; i <= phrase.length(); i++)
```

**Also:**

And it probably should be `<` instead of `<=` as well:

```
for (i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++) {
```

Comment: Ah, the semi-colon actually was the problem. Fixed! Thanks :) I also did switch phrase.substring(i, i + 1) with phrase.charAt(i).

Answer (score 2):

instead of `i <= phrase.length()` you should to use `i < phrase.length()`

Comment: *sight* getting points is harder and harder every day srsly didn't have 30 secs to look at the code

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis according to the Java Spec, the end index (i+1) is allowed to be equal to the length

Comment: @user2188341 remove the semicolon after `(for i = ..., i++)`, then it should work

Answer (score 0):

On line 83 i should be < phrase.length() not <= to it.

Fixed loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++) {
```

Comment: As I said, I have tried this, but I still get the same error... :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `phrase.substring(i,i+1)` at the last iteration it will get out out bounds.